# Removing Digits from a Number

Tags: swift, numbers, trim

Does anybody know if there is a way of removing (trimming) the last two digits or first two digits from a number. I have the number 4131 and I want to separate that into 41 and 31, but after searching the Internet, I've only managed to find how to remove characters from a string, not a number. I tried converting my number to a string, then removing characters, and then converting it back to a number, but I keep receiving errors.

I believe I will be able to receive the first two digit by dividing the number by 100 and then rounding the number down, but I don't have an idea of how to get the last two digits?

Does anybody know the function to use to achieve what I'm trying to do, or can anybody point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
var num = 1234

var first = num/100
var last = num%100
```

The playground's output is what you need.

[image: Playground]

Answer (score 5):

You can use below methods to find the last two digits

```
func getLatTwoDigits(number : Int) -> Int {
     return number%100; //4131%100 = 31
}
func getFirstTwoDigits(number : Int) -> Int {
    return number/100; //4131/100 = 41
}
```

To find the first two digit you might need to change the logic on the basis of face value of number. Below method is generalise method to find each digit of a number.

```
func printDigits(number : Int) {
    var num = number

    while num > 0 {
        var digit = num % 10 //get the last digit
        println("\(digit)")
        num = num / 10 //remove the last digit
    }
}
```