# Get nth digits of Integer in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point, numbers, integer

Let's say I have a value representing the year 1927. Now I want to get the last 2 digits of said year. Is there an efficient way of doing this in Swift? I figured out the following method based on my SO research thus far:

```
// My goal is to start with 1927 and end with 27

let fullYear = 1927 as Float  // --> 1927 
let valueToSubtract = Int(fullYear/100)  // --> 19
let splitNumber = fullYear/100 as NSNumber  // --> 19.27
let decimalValue = Float(splitNumber) - Float(valueToSubtract)  // -->0.2700005
let finalNumber = Double(round(1000 * decimalValue)/10)  // --> 27
```

This seems overly cumbersome. I'm fairly new to programming and Swift, am I missing a simpler way?

Comment: Not sure about Swift, but anywhere else I'd use modulo 100: something like `result = 1927 % 100`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474347/removing-digits-from-a-number/30474438#30474438

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Last two digits - use division modulo operator: `1927 % 100` gives `27`.

Comment: This is a little simpler than my method...thank you so much!